# Rails Activerecord migration from text to integer[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-migrations

I am using below:
Rails 5.0.1
PostgreSQL 11.5

I have a model called `Announcement` and it has a text column called `user_ids`.
Currently data in this column is in the format `"[7, 8, 75]"`.
I am trying to change this column's data type to integer[].

Here is what I wrote:

```
class ChangeUserIdsToArrayOnAnnouncements < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    change_column :announcements, :user_ids, :integer, array: true, default: [], using: "(string_to_array(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(user_ids, ' ', ''), '['), ']'), ','))"
  end

  def down
    change_column :announcements, :user_ids, :text, array: false, default: nil, using: "('[' || array_to_string(user_ids, ', ') || ']')"
  end
end
```

But above migration return below error:
`PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  result of USING clause for column "user_ids" cannot be cast automatically to type integer[]`

Can someone points me to right direction to do this migration?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that [`string_to_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) returns `text[]` (i.e. array of `text`) rather than the `integer[]` that you need. The easiest solution is throw an extra `::int[]` typecast in:

```
using: "string_to_array(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(user_ids, ' ', ''), '['), ']'), ',')::int[]"
```

There's no default cast from `text[]` to `int[]` so you have to be explicit and tell the database what you want it to do.

Comment: I tried but it did not work. See below output:
```-- change_column(:announcements, :user_ids, :integer, {:array=>true, :default=>[], :using=>"string_to_array(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(user_ids, ' ', ''), '['), ']'), ',')::int[]"})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""[7"
: ALTER TABLE "announcements" ALTER COLUMN "user_ids" TYPE integer[] USING string_to_array(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(user_ids, ' ', ''), '['), ']'), ',')::int[]```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is what worked:

```
class ChangeUserIdsToArrayOnAnnouncements < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    change_column :announcements, :user_ids, :integer, array: true, default: [], using: "REPLACE(translate(user_ids, '[]', '{}'), '\"', '')::int[]"
  end

  def down
    change_column :announcements, :user_ids, :text, array: false, default: nil, using: "('[' || array_to_string(user_ids, ', ') || ']')"
  end
end
```